# How to use strings as objects and subsets when subsetting data frames

Tags: r

I have a data frame I'd like to subset using a user input. The user would submit a file with three fields: data frame to subset, the subset conditions, and the columns to select. An example line in `file.txt` would be:

```
"mtcars","mpg > 21 & hp > 100",""
```

Would use data frame `mtcars`, subset all those with `mpg > 21` and `hp > 100`, and select all columns.

You could read this in with

```
query <- read.csv("file.txt", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then run `subset` with

```
subset(as.name(query$V1), query$V2)
```

This doesn't work as it doesn't recognize `query$V2` as a logical statement and it doesn't detect the columns of `as.name(query$V1)`. Is such a thing possible? Is there a better way to do this? I need to be able to run multiple subsets/queries against data frames by users through file input.

Comment: Hard to know for sure with your example, but this should work in the simple `mtcars` one: `eval(parse(text="subset(mtcars,mpg>21 & hp>100)"))`

Comment: `mtcars` is a built in dataset, but yes this seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard evaluation versions of the dplyr functions allow you to do this while not allowing the same kind of arbitrary code execution allowed by eval(parse(text=))

```
library(dplyr)

# Read user input
user_input <- data_frame("mtcars","mpg > 21 & hp > 100", "cyl, mpg, hp") %>% 
  as.list()

# Find user specified data.frame
out <- get(user_input[[1]])

# Filter data by user input
if (user_input[[2]] != '') {
  out <- out %>% 
    filter_(.dots = user_input[[2]])
}

# Select user specified cols
if (user_input[[3]] != '') {
  # assuming the col names are comma separated
  user_input[[3]] <- unlist(strsplit(user_input[[3]], ','))
  out <- out %>% 
    select_(.dots = user_input[[3]])
}

out
```

Comment: I like the idea and thought of something like this too, but there are multiple operators that could divide terms and some could be grouped. Addressing the entire subset string as one is best as not to cut up already correctly formatted input. Of course, I'd need to check if the `user_input[[2]]` in your case is correctly formatted

Comment: filter can actually handle logical operators so you wouldn't need to chop up the subsetting expression. I've edited the answer accordingly.